# openerp 7: displaying Manufacturing Orders for Sales Order

Tags: odoo

I have created a custom entity that lets us select a sales order. The desire is that when a sales order is selected, it should show a list of manufacturing orders linked to that sales order.

How to go about getting this in place? And what should be in the mode? fields.related or fields.one2many?

Thanks

code:

```
class my_custom(osv.osv):
    _name = 'mrp.mycustom'
    _columns={
          'name': fields.char('Name',size=64),
          'salesorder_id': fields.many2one('sale.order','Sales Order')
          }
my_custom()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct link between sale order and manufacturing order. You need to add a link first.then you you can use a one2many to show your manufacturing order

Comment: Manufacturing orders have a source document property which is sufficient for me. Either with that or assuming i add a field called salesorder_id to a child of mrp.production, what would be the steps to achieve the above?